# Take a look at my proguard file - is something wrong?

Tags: android, proguard

What should I write inside my proguard file to keep all classes/interfaces/enums this jar uses? https://github.com/bulldog2011/nano

This is what my proguard file looks like right now:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.**

-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
-keep class amazon.** { *; }
-keep class com.loopj.** { *; }
-keep class com.leansoft.** { *; }
```

But when I'm launching my app in release-mode, not everything works. In debug mode everything works.

So it must be something in the proguard...

Comment: Post your error caused by progaurd

Comment: I don't have errors caused by proguard... My error is inside the app but it only happens in the app-release and not in the app-debug

Comment: share the error the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: @DevrimTuncer the logcat monitors the debug version. Is there a way to make it monitor the release version? The error only rises in the release-version

Comment: list all packages in the jar and from the list, build up the config declares to bypass the jar